# Routing errors when upgrading from rails 3.1 to rails 3.2 due to underscores in module namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We have a rails application and we have a API namespace defined as Api::V1, Api::V1_2, Api::V1_3 etc.

In routes.rb, we have set the following

```
namespace :api do
  ["v1", "v1.2", "v1.3", "latest"].each do |name|
    namespace name, {:module => name.gsub(".","__"), :as => name.gsub(".","_") } do
      constraints :format => /json/ do

      # user scoped views

      resources :some_endpoint, :only => [:create, :index, :show, :update, :delete], :path => "scheduler" do
        member do
          put 'edit'
          post 'duplicate'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine when running with Rails 3.1, but we get a routing error in rails 3.2 of the form:

```
[INFO  pid: 17025: 14-07-28 19:06:15 ] Started GET "/api/v1.2/commands/1" for 192.168.1.130 at Mon Jul 28 19:06:15 -0700 2014
[FATAL pid: 17025: 14-07-28 19:06:15 ]
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V12):
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:219:in `constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:218:in `constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  sass (3.2.6) lib/sass/./sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
```

The above translates to Api::V1_2 when we run it with rails 3.1.

Any idea what might be the error here and how do I fix it? The code works fine in all other cases including rendering of assets etc. Only in this case does rails throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across same thing once.
There was this bug on their github issue list

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5849

Then a pull request

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6105

But the discussion did not come to any solution. The common statement was like

> Don't like undescores in Modules.

So you'll have to remove your underscores from the Module names