# How to deal with "dots" in a namespace (module) in Rails/Ruby (API version contains a "dot" -- V2.4)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an API of version 2.4. I just happen to have it and there's no way to rename it. How can I deal with it in Rails? I can't create a namespace with a dot in its name:

```
module Api::V2.4
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily I would recommend using an underscore instead of a dot:

```
module Api::V2_4
```

Unfortunately, Rails [has issues with underscores in module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008028/routing-errors-when-upgrading-from-rails-3-1-to-rails-3-2-due-to-underscores-in), so you'll have to do something ugly like this:

```
module Api::V24
```

Or:

```
module Api::V2Dot4
```

Comment: clear? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981867/rails-cant-find-a-route-with-an-underscore-or-doesnt-treat-it-properly

Comment: I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't think there's a pretty solution.