# Can't find a route with an underscore or doesn't treat it properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have this in routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v3_4 do
      # .....
```

And the controller `app/controllers/api/v3_4/base_controller`

```
module Api
  module V3_4
    class BaseController < ApplicationController
      # ......
    end
  end
end
```

And  `app/controllers/api/v3_4/another_controller`

```
module Api
  module V3_4
    class AnotherController < ApplicationController

    end
  end

end
```

rake routes:

```
          Prefix Verb        URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
   api_v3_4_test GET         /api/v3_4/test(.:format)        api/v3_4/base#test
 api_v3_4_one GET|OPTIONS /api/v3_4/one(.:format)      api/v3_4/another#one
        api_v3_4 GET|OPTIONS /api/v3_4/two/:id(.:format)  api/v3_4/another#two
```

And yet for this request I get `Routing Error Uninit Constant uninitialized constant Api::V34`

Note there's no underscore in the error message. 
But my project there's no line V34 at all, neither v34, only v3_4 and V3_4

Comment: It seems I may have given you bad advice in my answer to your previous question. Apparently Rails has issues with underscores in module names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008028/routing-errors-when-upgrading-from-rails-3-1-to-rails-3-2-due-to-underscores-in

Comment: You may just have to name your module `V34` or `V3Dot4`, neither of which is ideal.

Comment: That is how rails does things (the same as how another_controller is mapped to AnotherController). You may be able to get around this with custom inflections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails inflects `_` to be a word separator, so it searches for Api::V34 you can change that behavior by editing `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'V3_4'
end
```

Moreover, if you want to change `Api` namespace to `API`, since it's an acronym, you can do it there as well:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'V3_4'
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

Comment: It seems that this does not work in Rails 4.2, as I cannot make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby-Style-Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) helped me a lot to clarify these questions. Please see the [naming](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming) section.