# How to direct a form to a specific controller's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

New "developer" here.  I'm trying to learn how to create forms for our existing application, and I'm tearing my hair out.
Controller:

```
class DigitalRecipientsController < ApplicationController
    def update
        @line_item = line_item params[:id]
        @recipients = @line_item.recipients 
        recipient = @recipients.create! :name => @new_name, :email => @new_email
    end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :digital_recipients
```

template html.erb, (within a loop of @line_items.each |line_item|):

```
<%= form_for line_item, :url => {:controller => 'digital_recipients', :action => 'update'} do |f| %>
   <%= f.label 'name: ' %><%= f.text_field(:name, value: @new_name) %>
   <%= f.label ', email: ' %><%= f.text_field(:email, value: @new_email) %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This throws and exception:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"digital_recipients"}
```

I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY?!!?  How do I point this form to that controller's method 'update'?

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have a DigitalRecipients model ? The problem is with how you define your routes.

Comment: I do, but it's empty.

Comment: Be careful with routes, the underscore is understood as a word separator then there is a problem rooting underscored resources. If you want to keep your resource `digital_recipients` as it is in your routes you may have to add it to initializers/inflections.rb (even when mentionning your controller in form_for, it is then translated as an URL in your HTML view, then it's a routing problem)

Comment: If you are using rails 5 then run `rails routes` or `bin/rake routes` for a lesser version of rails. Inspect the routes to see if you have the route listed.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981867/cant-find-a-route-with-an-underscore-or-doesnt-treat-it-properly

Comment: from my rake routs output:  
digital_recipient PATCH    /digital_recipients/:id(.:format)                                                 digital_recipients#update
                                     PUT      /digital_recipients/:id(.:format)                                                 digital_recipients#update

Comment: What is line_item in '@line_item = line_item params[:id]'?

Comment: @adcosta yep and on this line `recipient = @recipients.create! :name => @new_name, :email => @new_email` `@new_name` and `@new_email` don't look like having been set anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= form_for line_item, url: digital_recipient_path(line_item), method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'name: ' %><%= f.text_field(:name, value: @new_name) %>
  <%= f.label ', email: ' %><%= f.text_field(:email, value: @new_email) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```